# Play! Framework with JBoss AOP?

Tags: jboss, playframework, aop

Was anybody succesfull in using Play! together with JBoss AOP? Is it generally possible?

Answer (score 0):

Play uses Java so in theory they are compatible, but I've never tried nor seen any module to easily link them.